# When trying to update an instance of related models I get the Ids on the template instead of the names, using {{form}}

Tags: django

URLS.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('stock/update/<int:pk>/', views.StockUpdateView, name='stock-update'),
```

VIEWS.py

```py
def StockUpdateView(request, pk):
     stock = Stock.objects.get(id=pk)
     form = StockForm(instance=stock)
     
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = StockForm(request.POST, instance=stock)
          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return redirect('/inventory/stock')
     context = {"form": form}
     return render(request, 'inventory/update-stock.html', context)
```

TEMPLATE.html

```html
<form action="" method="POST" class="row g-3">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <h6>Stock update form:</h6>
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-control">
          {{field}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

MODEL.py

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Stocks"

    name = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, default=0 ,validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("stock-update", args=[self.pk])

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_id} {self.quantity} {self.product_price}"
```

I have changed from using the {{ form }} tag to looping over the fields trying to get the name of the related table instead of the IDs.

Comment: share your models

Comment: if you would use ModelForm for Stock with ModelChoice querysets for name and product_id you will be to do what you want (see result of str methods for those querysets)